# How to cast groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator to user defined class

Tags: groovy, spock

I am writing a Integration Test class using `Spock Framework`, there my response hold inside `groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator`

I am trying to cast into my own class lets say `TestEntity` using following step

```
HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().delete([path: "$BASE_URL"+"/96023"])
```

Here the Path method returns `TestEntity`, Now I want to get that entity and write assertions

```
TestEntity entity = (TestEntity)response.getData()
```

When I write this statement I am getting `ERROR!
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object`

Comment: Does the `Object` returned from `getData()` implement `TestEntity`?

Comment: No, I updated question can you check it once

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible test case ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get help on StackOverflow. At least show a full Spock test and source code of all classes involved in that test, please.

Answer (score 0):

What class is returned by `getData()` depends on what content type returns the REST API you are calling.

Add this line to check what class is Groovy using in your case:

```
println response.data.getClass()
```

... or use debug in your IDE to obtain the same information.

For example for content type:

- `application/json` class `org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` is used
- `application/xml` class `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` is used
- `text/plain` class `java.io.StringReader` is used

---

If you are testing backend which uses the `TestEntity` class as a response (for example using `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping` in Spring) then you will not have `TestEntity` instance in the client (Spock test).